# Are Ignite's SQL Queries Transactional?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

We are implementing Apache Ignite's transaction using org.apache.ignite.transactions. Transaction object.

But we would like to know if it supports SQL Querying.

Comment: This may be useful https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/how-ignite-sql-works#section-known-limitations

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't properly use SQL transactions, though Ignite has an experimental support for MVCC.
I'd suggest you to keep using the Transaction object and K-V API.

Please, follow the links:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions#section-atomicity-mode and
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/multiversion-concurrency-control

Comment: Sorry, I can't use K-V Api because I'm having a case where I need to sort the entries of a particular column in a table. Don't know whether it could be achieved via K-V way?

Comment: Hello, can you share an example of your query?

Comment: Here's my use case. In Redis there is a datastructure zadd and zrange. zadd will add all the map K-V entries for a field F. Now V here is a double data type. Now on that data structure if you call zrange for 2 values of F, then you will get first two K-Vs sorted ascending by V. In Ignite case, I am creating a table for this. Since we are moving away from Redis.

Comment: Yes, Ignite doesn't preserve ordering for your caches and seems like the only chance to enforce it is to sort the values on a client. But you may take a look at other data structures such as a queue and a stack: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteQueue.html , also take a look at a #IgniteQueueExample from the sources.

Comment: We are using Ignite with persistence enabled. And the values to sort will range from millions to billions. If we perform a sort on the heap for big data it'll throw OOM and it won't be good to swap values in RAM and disk constantly. So, client sorting is not a good idea I guess. Currently, for a table with one double type column, we applied index in create schema.