# Is TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT support for OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE planned..?

Tags: transactions, ignite

According to Ignite 2.8.1 documentation "The TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT mode only supports the default concurrency mode (PESSIMISTIC) and default isolation level (REPEATABLE_READ). See Concurrency modes and isolation levels for details."

Is there a plan for TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT to support OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE?

Specifically, I am wondering if it is planned that SQL queries/operations will ever be supported with this setting..

Comment: Please, have a look at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226169/are-ignites-sql-queries-transactional/60226384#60226384

Answer (score 0):

`TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT` support is incomplete (not production-ready) and not being actively worked on, to my knowledge. Don't rely on its availability.